# Change attribute of django sub-object on save

Tags: django, foreign-key-relationship

I have two models, a Project and an Action:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Project Name", max_length=200, unique = True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Complete?")

class Action(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Action Name", max_length=200)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Project")
    notes = models.TextField("Notes", blank=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Complete?")
    status = models.IntegerField("Action Status", choices = STATUS, default=0)
```

When a Project is marked as complete, I'd like all of it's Actions to be marked as complete as well.

I'm trying to do this in the Project's save method:

```
    def save(self, **kw):
        self.last_modified = datetime.today()
        self.action.all().update(complete=True)

        super(Project, self).save(**kw)
```

I'm stuck on that third line above.  I'm not quite sure how to set all actions connected to this project to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the save method use...

```
Action.objects.filter(project = self).update(complete=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the hook system?

https://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/0_91/models/save_delete_hooks/

I think it's what you are looking for ;-)

Comment: this is very useful.  I'll look into it.  But in this instance, I'm not so much looking for how to trigger something on save.  I'm looking for how to execute a specific function.